# Django + DRF + Celery: execute celery_task.delay() only after database transaction completed (model.save() reached the database)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, celery, atomic, django-celery

I tried to use the on_commit method as they tell us in the docs, but I still get ModelDoesNotExistError inside the task launched via delay().

views.py:

```
class SomeViewset(viewsets.ModelViewset):
    ...
    @action(detail=True, methods=['post'])
    def some_action(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        m = MyModel()

        with transaction.atomic():
            m.save()
            transaction.on_commit(lambda:
                                      my_fav_task.delay(m.id, param2, param3))
        return Response({"success": True, "operation_id": m.id}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

tasks.py:

```
@shared_task
def my_fav_task(operation_id, **params):
    print(operation_id)  # We get new id
    print(MyModel.objects.all())  # No newly created object here
    operation = MyModel.objects.get(id=operation_id)  # Error here
```

Comment: For my your viewset is not good, you didnt get data in serializer and the save didnt do a thing

Comment: @MaximeK You made wrong assumption that any data is needed for the model. It can consist of one field, which is id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was in not obvious usage of different databases between celery and django. Seems that docker containers executing this processes created local db each for their own, because I unwillingly used standard db.sqlite3 without special sharing it. After changing DB settings to postgre, which was running in another container, the following pattern worked:

```
from django.db import transactions

@transaction.atomic
def view(request):
    m = MyModel()
    m.save()
    # Execute celery task only after database changes (m.save())
    transaction.on_commit(lambda: my_fav_task.delay(m.id, param2, param3))
    return Response({"success": True, "operation_id": m.id}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

The usage of lambda here is not good, because it is executed anyway. functools.partial should be used

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35584785)